# Best way to create a form that changes and gets information from multiple tables and queries

Tags: ms-access

I've been pondering this for a couple of days now, i have a relatively large database with multiple tables, and my goal is to be able to administrate this with a MS-Access application. This is the workflow that i want to achieve:
1. Choose a category of products
2. Choose a specific price list.
3. This lists all products of that category in this price list.
4. Choose an item in the list a
5. this triggers an update in a subform and fetches the data related to the choosen row
6. Choose the price in the subform for that specific type.

This problem triggers some newbie questions:
**1. How do i trigger an update in a datasheet from a drop down list, so that the datasheet only fetches products related to that category?

2. How do i make a subform trigger yet another subform to update?**
And third but not least
**3. Is there any good tutorials or other study material out there?**

If theres **anything** that is unclear please tell me and i will try to clarify the questions, english is not my native language. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access will do a lot without any code at all. For example, if your categories are listed in a listbox, that can be made to cascade to a second list box that shows only relevant price lists. Subforms have link child and link master fields that can refer to fields (columns) or controls. You can have a subset of records in the subform where the link master field(s) are the listbox(es) and the link child field(s) are the relevant related field(s). You can also refer to subform controls in link child and master fields.

You might like to look at the Northwind sample database that ships with all versions of Access, in particular, the Customer Order form.

Comment: Note that you have to be careful with what you copy from any of the sample Access databases as a number of "worst practices" are implemented there repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip to view the northwind DB, I think this might help me quite a bit. :)